# Is it possible to automatically generate a tag for with a post title name?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am working on a small project for church where I want to create filters for events happening on different locations.

For easy management, I created a specific Post Type for the event and another Post Type for the location.

In the location page, I call the events but right now all events are showing. My idea was to auto-generate tags with the location names and be able to select it from the event post type, so I can filter the results on the location page.

I managed to create a custom tag named after the locations, but I haven't had any ideas on how to auto-generate this tags from the names of every location added to the system.

This is [the link](http://ceizs.com.br/unidades/flamengo/) to the page I am working. It is in Portugues, so 'Eventos' mean Events. This page hasn't been translated yet.

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

```
function on_post_publish( $ID, $post ) {

    //Define the category
$my_cat = array('cat_name' => '', 'category_description' => '', 'category_nicename' => '', 'category_parent' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'unidadeseventos');

// Create the category
$my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);

}
add_action(  'publish_unidades',  'on_post_publish', 10, 2 );
```

I managed to write a function that creates the label as soon as I add a post, but I can't get it to have the name of the post. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did it!

So here is my code:

```
function on_post_publish( $ID, $post ) {
    // Get post title
    $parent_title = get_the_title( $post->post_parent );
    //Define the category
$my_cat = array('cat_name' => $parent_title, 'category_description' => '', 'category_nicename' => '', 'category_parent' => '', 'taxonomy' => 'unidadeseventos');

// Create the category
$my_cat_id = wp_insert_category($my_cat);

}
add_action(  'publish_unidades',  'on_post_publish', 10, 2 );
```